# Using a Angular filter as a function inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I had a function (`shortenNum`) that "shortens" a number by adding a "K" or a "M" to the end of it and stripping zeroes.  I decided to turn it into a filter, because I'm on Angular.

The filter/function has to be applied *inside of a directive, and not the markup*.  I injected the filter itself inside the directive, but the function itself, when I try to use it, is throwing the error:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: shortenNumProvider <- shortenNum <- d3PieDirective
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=shortenNumProvider%20%3C-%20shortenNum%20%3C-%20d3PieDirective...**

**Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('d3Pie', [
  '$window', 
  'd3Service', 
  'shortenNum',
  function($window, d3Service, shortenNum) {
  return {
    ...

  // eventually call
  return shortenNum(d.data.count);
```

**Filter:**

```
// Rewrites a given number in a shorthand form
myApp.filter('shortenNum', function(num) {
  if(num > 99999) { return (num/1000000).toFixed(1) + 'M'; }
  if(num > 999) { return (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K'; }
  return num;
});
```

**First:**  Is this even how filters should be used?

**Second:**  If so, what's my syntactical/conceptual mistake?

Comment: where's the filter declaration? Doesn't seem to be valid since the error is related to injecting it

Comment: whoops, I need a filter declaration?  Is that like a `$filter` injected into the directive?

Comment: added my filter, not sure exactly what you're asking...

Comment: yes it is, somethings not right regarding injection , not sure why. That `filter()` declaration is what i was talking about

Comment: @zelliott inject the `$filter` service itself into your `d3Pie` directive and then you can invoke your `shortenNum` filter in the form of: `$filter('shortenNum')(array, expression, comparator)`.

Comment: `filter()` should really return a function. See example filter in docs tutorrial here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the 2 ways you can use your filter in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1844/

Using a filter in a directive or service is perfectly acceptable, but you need to inject the filter into the directive.  You could inject `$filter`, but in the spirit of only requiring exactly what you need, it's probably better to inject the individual filter like so:

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('controllerFilter', function (shortNumFilter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            num:'@'
        },
        template: '<span>controllerFilter: {{ filteredNum }}</span>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('num', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                $scope.filteredNum = shortNumFilter(newVal);
            })
        }
     }
})
```